# Why is my Chrome so slow?

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome

Chrome became slow. Why is that? Firefox is much faster in Ubuntu, but I prefer Chrome, because it gives more "space". Thank you.

Comment: There's a Firefox Extension that makes Firefox use less vertical space.

Comment: Google chrome is slow.. Chromium isn't. What are u using ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not clear if this is a fresh install with a new profile. But it can happen that any browser's performance can degrade over time for various reasons: for example, conflicting extensions or some file being corrupted in one's profile.

First you could try creating a new "profile": with Chrome not running, simply rename the folder that has your details: `home/yourname/.config/google-chrome/Default` to something else. When you restart Chrome, it will create a new `Default`. Mostly, this solves most problems. For more details, consult the Linux section in [Create a new browser user profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059).

(If you have valuable bookmarks, you could export them as html before creating the new profile and import them later via Chrome's Bookmark Manager.)

If the browser performs well with the new profile, it could point to an issue with extensions you had installed. Some ad block extensions are known to affect performance, at least on some pages. If it's a problem with a single extension, all can be disabled and enabled one by one to see when performance degrades. You can get at your extensions by clicking on `Customize and Control Google Chrome`, `Tools`, `Extensions` or by entering `chrome://extensions` in the address bar and hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

You can also clear cache, cookies, and browsing history by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> together and making appropriate choices.

If you provide more details, someone may have specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you remove browser history and try to reinstal, it will work quite a bit faster...
dit the trick for me :)

Comment: Can you explain how?

Answer (score -2):

use click and clean extension. It clears all cache during exit.

Comment: Why an extension you can do that from the preferences menu...

Comment: Also, can you edit this to provide more information about how to obtain and use that extension, perhaps including screenshots as well as descriptive text?